# Updating Views asynchronously

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, thread-exceptions

I am trying to populate a `recyclerview` with data from the web which I want to fetch asynchronously.

I have a function `loadData()` which is called `onCreateView()` which first makes a loading Indicator visible, then calls the suspend function loading the data and then tries to notify the view adapter to update.

But at this point I get the following exception:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

which surprised me as my understanding was that only my `get_top_books()` function was called on a different thread and previously when I was showing the loading indicator I was apparently on the right thread.

So why is this run-time exception raised?

My code:

```
class DiscoverFragment: Fragment() {

    lateinit var loadingIndicator: TextView
    lateinit var viewAdapter: ViewAdapter
    var books = Books(arrayOf<String>("no books"), arrayOf<String>("no books"), arrayOf<String>("no books"))

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val viewFrame = layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false)

        val viewManager = GridLayoutManager(viewFrame!!.context, 2)
        viewAdapter = ViewAdapter(books)
        loadingIndicator = viewFrame.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.loading_indicator)

        val pxSpacing = (viewFrame.context.resources.displayMetrics.density * 8f + .5f).toInt()

        val recyclerView = viewFrame.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = viewAdapter
            addItemDecoration(RecyclerViewDecorationSpacer(pxSpacing, 2))
        }

        loadData()

        return viewFrame
    }

    fun loadData() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val task = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            get_top_books()
        }
        books = task.await()
        viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `Dispatchers.Main` for `loadData()` function

Comment: `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`?

Comment: Consider using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)` instead of `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch`.

Comment: Also consider `books = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { get_top_books() }`, since you don't need the concurrency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After calling `books = task.await()` you are outside UI thread. It is because you use `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)`. Change it to `Dispatchers.Main`:

```
fun loadData() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val task = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            get_top_books()
        }
        books = task.await()
        viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. So the ```await()``` call removed me from the UI thread? If I change the Dispatcher.Default to Dispatchers.Main I get the following runtime exception: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize ``` ```Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.String kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory.hintOnError()"```

Comment: @JoschkaGoes Have you added `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.0` to your dependencies?

Comment: @DominicFischer I just checked and I was on 1.0.1 and upgrading to 1.1.0 solved my issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After calling `books = task.await()` you are outside UI thread. You should run all UI related code in the main thread. To do this you can use `Dispatchers.Main`.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Or using `Handler`

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { 
    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Or you can use `Activty` instance to call `runOnUiThread` method.

```
activity!!.runOnUiThread {
    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    loadingIndicator.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Comment: Thanks the ```Handler``` method works, but I get an runtime exception if I use Dispatchers.Main

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `Dispatchers.Default` to `Dispatchers.Main` and upgrading my version of `kotlinx-coroutines-android` to `1.1.1` did the trick.

Changing

```
val task = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    get_top_books()
}
books = task.await()
```

to

```
books = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    get_top_books()
}
```

is also a bit more elegant. Thanks to everyone who responded especially @DominicFischer who had the idea to check my dependencies.

Comment: Remember that suspend function `withContext()` should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Answer (score 0):

UI related statements should be performed in the UI thread, I can't tell from the linked code only, but maybe you are changing UI in thsi function `get_top_books()`.

Just put the related UI code in the UI thread like this

```
runOnUiThread(
    object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "runOnUiThread")
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: ```get_top_books()``` is currently just a function wich creates an empty data class of type ```Books``` and then sleeps for some time so that should not be the issue. And is there a way to call ```runOnUiThread()``` from my fragment? Quickly looking that up gave me the impression that this is an Activity thing.